# NTFS, can the files set to be placed in the inner-most part of the HDD platter(s)?

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive, ntfs

Without setting multiple partitions (this is a well-known workaround, but I preffer not to) or using a defragmenter after the files are written (hence 2x more activity for the HDD), is it possible to configure the filesystem (or something else) to start placing the files from the inner-most part of the platter and NOT the outer-most? More like make the HDD archive-like and leave the outer-most part empty for high-speed or temp files later on.

Comment: Your explanation is nice to have, but I feel like a piece of the puzzle is still missing: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Conviniently, I would like to have a folder that whatever is placed there is getting in the outer-most part (temp files) and another folder that whatever is placed there is getting in the inner-most part (archive data). That way I solve most of the fragmentation problem, but I am not sure that this level of convenience is possible

Comment: are you sure defragmenters put file at the end of partitions?

Comment: Ultimate defrag has this capability

Comment: I feel unable to give an answer that applies to a three digit number of available file systems. Which file system are you talking about?

Comment: Its in the question itself,NTFS

Comment: If speed is the issue, buy an SSD. Smaller SSDs now are not expensive. Although low cost, long life, speed, choose any two may still apply. I even found moving my M.2 SSD to USB port with adapter to be almost as fast as internal SSD and faster than internal HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Short version of my answer: NO!

The effect you wish to obtain cannot be configured in NTFS.
There is just one point of access to the location of files. It is the defragmentation API:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/defragmenting-files

To reach your goal you would have to patch or reprogram the file system driver.
But even is this was possible, the driver would not know what to put where because the file system API has no parameter flag to tell if a file belongs to temp storage or regular storage. Every program would have to be rewritten for that purpose.

Only in the few cases where a folder path contains "\temp" the file system could reasonably guess that this file is supposed to exist only a limited time.

My advice is: Use different partitions and/or different drives. With your awareness of fragmentation you will most likely avoid excess fragmentation.

Rather than asking for such an exotic task you might describe your problems with excess fragmentation. Maybe there is an easier solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but your reply answers to the comment I added about the "convenience" I described. I know that you cannot tell if a file belongs to temp or regular storage, thats why I said it would be very convenient. Still, the answer to if I can make the data to be written in the opposite direction is not answered.

Comment: In case of my explanation appears to difficult: The answer is NO!

Answer (score 0):

When the OS talks to the SATA controller, it simply asks the controller to read/write a specific Logical Block Address (LBA).  LBA's start at 0 and go up to the billions or trillions depending on the size of the drive.

There's no concept of "where" the data is going.  That concept was valid when floppies were around (you had to tell the floppy which side [head], track [cylinder], and sector) but when IDE hard drives started to come into vogue, that responsibility became fully offloaded to the drive and was never really controllable.  It did take a while for the old Cylinder-Head-Sector addressing to go away and be replaced with Logical Block Addressing, but hard drives outgrew CHS quickly and CHS never was a true reflection of any hard drive topology since the early 90's IIRC.

Because of that the operating system API is not going to support that.

LBA 0 *might* be the innermost or outermost cylinder, but there's no guarantees and it's possible a hard drive manufacturer has done something weird with platters/cylinders internally.  Unless you really test access times sector by sector or have access to documentation you don't really know what's happening.

The one thing known with hard drives is that reading LBA N+1 when you've just read LBA N is really fast most of the time.  So filesystem drivers will try to keep like data together, but they have no way of really knowing which LBAs are on which cylinders.

You will need to create multiple partitions and reserve one for mostly read-only data and other for more volatile data.